# How to convert all DATETIME variables in a SAS table to DATE9

Tags: loops, date, sas, datetime-format

I have a table in SAS in which all my variables that represent dates are in DATETIME20. format and I want to convert them to DATE9. format. Let's say I have 3 datetime variables in my SAS table (date1, date2, date3) and I want to convert them to DATE9. while keeping their original names (date1, date2, date3). I want the code to be flexible, such that if I change variable names - change the names of (date1, date2, date3) in the preamble of the code - then the code still works, i.e. I want the code to work for different names and number of those date variables. I have this code in SAS:

```
%let dates = ('date1', 'date2', 'date3');

data my_table;
set my_table;
    array numvars _NUMERIC_;
    do _t = 1 to dim(numvars);
        if upcase(vname(numvars[_t])) in &dates. then do;
            numvars[_t] = datepart(numvars[_t]);
        end;
    end;
run;
```

However, this does not convert my (date1, date2, date3) variables into DATE9. but they still remain DATETIME variables with incorrect values after this transformation. I want to be able to change &dates. macro variable on the first line such that I don't have to change the code after that line.

Comment: Do you KNOW that DATE1, DATE2 and DATE3 already exist on your input dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to changing the value stored from seconds to days (by using DATEPART() function) you also need to change the format used to display the values.  Make the macro variable just hold the list of variable names so that it can be used in SAS code.

```
%let dates = date1 date2 date3 ;

data my_table;
  set my_table;
  array dtvars &dates ;
  do _t = 1 to dim(dtvars);
    dtvars[_t] = datepart(dtvars[_t]);
  end;
  format &dates date9.;
run;
```

If you want to make it even more dynamic then use the FMTINFO() function to find the existing DATETIME variables.   The FMTINFO() function wants just the format name and not a full format specification so it is easier to work with the output of PROC CONTENTS than the dictionary views.

```
%let dsnin=example;
%let dsnout=example_date;

proc contents data=&dsnin noprint out=contents; run;

proc sql noprint;
 select nliteral(name)
   into :varlist separated by ' '
   from contents 
   where fmtinfo(format,'cat')='datetime'
 ;
%let nvars=&sqlobs;
quit;

data &dsnout;
  set &dsnin;
%if &nvars %then %do;
  array _dt &varlist ;
  do over _dt; _dt = datepart(_dt); end;
  format &varlist date9.;
%end;
run;
```

You could even change the SQL query to only test the specific variables you have put in your DATES macro variable.

```
   where fmtinfo(format,'cat')='datetime'
     and findw("&dates",name,' ','sit')
```

Comment: Very cool, very flexible, thanks. I wish I could program like that too.